# VBA For loop skipping the first iteration

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm trying to write a macro to detect if a cell contains a certain word. If yes, copy the entire row to the next empty row.

In this case, I'm trying to detect "60s" from  "Full Length, 60s, 30s, 15s, Sting".

Here's what I've got, but it only copies and pastes the last qualified row, skipping the first iteration.

```
Private Sub Button_Click()

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lr
    If InStr(Cells(i, "G"), "60s") > 0 Then
        Rows(i).Copy Rows(lr + 1)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I see, your code first looks at column `A` to find the last used row and puts result into variable `lr`. Then it goes through every row from `2` to `lr` (determined by column `A` and looks at values in column `G`. If the value contains "60s", the row is copied below row `lr`.

Let's start with this dataset:

[image]

After you find your value in column `G`, the row is copied below row `lr`:
[image]

After another time you find your value in column `G`, the row is copied again **below row `lr`**:
[image]

Now you can see the problem. The 3rd time we see the same thing:
[image]

So, it's evident that you keep copying on top of previous results, because `lr` was defined at the beginning and it doesn't change. We can fix it using `lr=lr+1` exactly after the `Copy` line. So this will do what you want:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lr
    If InStr(Cells(i, "G"), "60s") > 0 Then
        Rows(i).Copy Rows(lr + 1)
        lr = lr + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with the assessment, but disagree with the solution: incrementing `lr` inside of a loop where `lr` is used to control the looping behavior is kind of a bad idea. It isn't going to loop endlessly (I think in VBA, the exit point for the loop becomes fixed and incrementing the variable after the first `FOR` pass won't extend the looping), but it could in other languages and probably should be avoided. It would be better to change `[...].Rows(lr+1)` to `[...].Rows(lr +i-1)`